# Python Tkinter get result of askopenfilenames()

Tags: python, tkinter

I use Tkinter as GUI library and i need to get list of files which i choose by calling askopenfilenames.
Here is my function^

```
def choose_file(file_list)
    file_list = fd.askopenfilenames()
file_list = ()
b1 = Button(command = lambda: choose_file(file_list))
```

file_list - is variable in outer scope. But after calling function, this var is empty. What i did wrong?

Comment: you need `global file_list` at the start of your function definition.

Comment: Why are you passing in `file_list` as parameter.

Comment: @TheLizzard That would give an error right? As parameter are globalized by default?

Comment: @CoolCloud only mutable objects are global if they have no scope.

Comment: @TheLizzard Yea thats what, parameters are global already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import tkinter as tk

def choose_file():
    global file_list
    file_list = fd.askopenfilenames()

file_list = ()
root = tk.Tk()
b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=choose_file)
b1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The variable `file_list` is not global as it is immutable. To make it global you have to add `global file_list` to the start of your function definition. For more info read: [Why you can change immutable if it's global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583851/why-you-can-change-immutable-if-its-global).

Answer (score 0):

You have two different `file_list` variables in your code. One at global scope

```py
file_list = ()
```

and one at function scope.

```py
def choose_file(file_list):
```

With

```py
    file_list = fd.askopenfilenames()
```

you are assigning the list returned by `askopenfilenames` to the function scope variable - everywhere in the function, `file_list` will have the list from `askopenfilenames` as value, what you can see by adding `print(file_list)`  to your function twice, one time at the beginning and one time at the end.

To modify the global variable instead of the local one, you can either make the local (function scope) variable global

```py
file_list = ()

def choose_file():
    global file_list
    file_list = fd.askopenfilenames()

b1 = Button(command = choose_file)
```

where the variable initialization must be moved before the function declaration (I think else it gives an `UnboundLocalError` or something), the lambda can be removed, and you do not need to pass `file_list` as an argument.